# Indexes Size 20 times bigger then the table itself and very slow queries

Tags: postgresql

The table I want to query has only about ~3000 rows with 3 columns:

```
int/varchar(100)/varchar(100)
```

yet it takes ~30 sec to query them all!

Then I saw that the table size is 1331MB but the indexes size is 25GB!

The table has only one index and that is the pkey.

`VACCUM FULL` is running every 24hours and the table sould be pretty static anyway

My question is why are the indexes so big (I guess thats why the querys are so slow) and what can I do to fix that?

Hope you have any ideas, because I have none and I haven't found anything on google.

EDIT: Postgres Version is 8.1.18

Comment: You should have mentioned your Postgres version (8.4, 9.0, ...) VACUUM FULL is known to bloat the indexes (in versions before 9.0). It is a last ressort thing to do and should not be done on a regular basis. Stop the VACUUM FULL (only do a regular VACUUM). Do a REINDEX once and you should be fine.

Comment: 8.1 has been discontinued a **long** time ago. Newer versions have made many enhancements in the VACUUM area and you should upgrade to a supported version ***now***!

Comment: Make sure to **prominently mention that you're on 8.1.18 in any future questions**. Almost everything requires a different answer for 8.1. Though that answer will usually be "omfg, upgrade".

Comment: i will and "omfg, upgrade" was my first reaction too ;-) but i'll be over soon enough.

Comment: I'm glad this got solved, but can we talk about why a table with three small fields and 3K rows weighs 1331MB? Is that normal? I would have expected it to weigh on the order of 1-3 MB (excluding indexes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Pre-9.0 `VACUUM FULL`

You're on PostgreSQL 8.4 or older, where `VACUUM FULL` tends to *bloat indexes*. See [this wiki page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL) for details.

Don't run `VACUUM FULL` as a periodic maintenance task. It's unnecessary and inefficient. This remains true on current versions, it's just not as bad on 9.0 and above. If you feel the need to run `VACUUM FULL` regularly then you probably don't have autovacuum turned up far enough and are having table bloat issues. In fact, unless you've changed the `FILLFACTOR` on the table from its default `100` a `VACUUM FULL` is quite counter-productive; it'll compact away all the free space in the table, so following `UPDATE`s will have to extend the table.

Table extensions are currently one of the poorer performing operations in PostgreSQL, as they're controlled by a single global lock. So if you have tables that fluctuate in size, you really want to avoid constantly compacting and truncating them only to extend them again.

On some unusual workloads it can be worth running a periodic `CLUSTER`, which orders the table based on an index and effectively `REINDEX`es it. If you do many `UPDATE`s on the table should set a lower `FILLFACTOR` for efficiency.

If this table is being emptied and re-populated regularly, you should generally using `TRUNCATE`  followed by `COPY` to fill it back up. If it's big, drop the indexes before the `COPY` then re-create them afterwards to produce indexes that are more compact and faster and to speed up the data load.

For one-off mitigation, `CLUSTER` the table or `REINDEX` it.

### 8.1?!?!

**After edit added version**: Holy bleepazoids, batman. 8.1.18? Forget what I said about autovacuum, autovacuum in 8.1 was way too ineffective. **Upgrade to a sane version ASAP**. You're not even on the current point release of 8.1, 8.1.23, from December 2010. 8.1.18 was released in September 2009! You need to begin your upgrade planning ... well, about two years ago, preferably. Read the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html) for every .0 version between 8.1 and the current release, focusing on the upgrade notes and compatibility notes. Then plan and execute your upgrade. If you don't feel up managing that on your own there are [people who'll help you with it](http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/) (I work for one of them) but honestly, the release notes and docs are quite sufficient for most people to do an upgrade themselves without undue pain.

Moving from 8.1 to 8.3 or newer will be your biggest pain point, as PostgreSQL 8.3 dropped a whole bunch of implicit casts that lots of potentially buggy SQL relied on. You'll need to test your application carefully on the newer version. Other changes to be aware of are:

- The removal of implicit `FROM` and in later versions removal of the backwards compatibility parameter for it;
- UTF-8 validation improvements in newer versions that can cause older dumps to fail to load until the data is corrected;
- The change to `standard_conforming_strings` by default;
- The change of `bytea_output` to `hex`

Comment: @Patrick These are the kinds of details you should put in your original questions. *"I'm on 8.1.18; I know it's ancient and unsupported, but I can't upgrade since we're retiring the system a few months, so I'm looking for workaround/mitigation options"*.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me once on 9.1.

I had a script that would process large size of data and then insert in the db. The issue showed up in the initial data import.

I didn't find the cause of this but a workaround was to  drop the index and recreate it.

You could also pg_dump and then pg_restore the whole db, and this will also recreate the index.

Comment: `REINDEX` would be rather better than drop and re-create if you can't avoid the root cause.